# Android Notification, do stuff on click

Tags: android, notifications

I've read documentation. But i found only a way to call my activity on click with Intent

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyMain.class), 0);
```

But how do i make some action, e.g switching view in wievflipper and only then opening activity?
I tried reading about .putExtra() method, but it only can add constant - value. I need to swtich my wievlipper screen with `flipper.SetDisplayedChild(i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the view flipping logic in onCreate()

Comment: i need to do this action when clicking on notification. on clicking notification i don't recreate my activity.